# huge data from a file to database using java?

Tags: java, mysql, bigdata

i am able to load a huge text file data into database where the number of lines are 33264591.
I used normal **BufferedReader** for reading line by line and able to push the data.
Here it is taking enormous time for loading almost 3 hrs for reading line by line and insert into database.

Could some one suggest me better way for Quick insertion of data using java?

Thank you in advance

Comment: which database are you using you didn't specify

Comment: @aaronman: Mysql for test run

Answer (score 0):

Well, before going any further, I would suggest using a profiler and finding out why it takes so much time. If you know where the problem is, it would be easier to fix.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the best way to read huge files are using BufferedReader and reading it line by line. So this is what you are doing. I am wondering if you are inserting the data in the same loop where you are reading the file. The only optimization i can think of in your scenario is to do the database inserts in a separate thread so that you should not block your file reading because of any delay in the DB inserts. DB inserts will gradually start to become slower and slower as the size of your table grows. So doing DB inserts in a separate thread will be a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

Do batch inserts instead of inserting one row at a time.